# SQL oracle, display the output correctly

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, inner-join

[image]

I stuck a bit with the output....

Question:
Need to lists groups and the members belonging to each group.  For each group show the unique identifier and its name (if any).  For each member, show the unique identifier, the name, gender, date of birth and identifier of their group leader.  Within each group, sort members by surname and forename.

My answer:

```
  SELECT 
      P.Name,
      P.DOB,
      P.Gender,
      G.GroupName,
      GL.PersonId   
FROM Person P
INNER JOIN GroupMember GM ON GM.PersonId =  P.PersonId
INNER JOIN Group G ON G.GroupId =  P.GroupId
INNER JOIN GroupLeader GL ON GL.GroupId = G.GroupId
```

The question is, how to display correctly  this question using the Logical ERD with it at the top of this post....

For my answer I have like this:BUT I create this tables, OR i missed some think((

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Comment: The only valid table name given your ERD is Person the rest are not listed in your diagram.

Comment: Can you explain how do I have to list it in correct way to make it display correctly?

Comment: gMember is not a valid table name - your table is called 'GroupMember' - the same goes for groupTab and gLeader

Comment: I will edit in a sec..

Comment: I just rename them)) when i did my actual table with data

Comment: Can you tell me how do I have to connect them to make it display correctly? I just really confused a bit, can't get it how it's works(((

Comment: Are you still getting the same error - 'table or view does not exist'? Are you sure your table really exists then? Can you run `select * from tablename` without an error for each table?

Comment: Yes) I can see all the tables

Comment: Any suggestions about this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
 INNER JOIN gLeader GL ON GL.group_idG.group_id
```

is invalid.  Shouldn't it be this?

```
 INNER JOIN gLeader GL ON GL.group_id = G.group_id
```

**Edit starts here**

Start with this:

```
SELECT 

  -- P.Name
  -- , P.DOB
  -- , P.Gender
  -- , G.GroupName
  -- , GL.PersonId   

 count(*)
 FROM Person P
 -- INNER JOIN GroupMember GM ON GM.PersonId =  P.PersonId
 -- INNER JOIN Group G ON G.GroupId =  P.GroupId
 -- INNER JOIN GroupLeader GL ON GL.GroupId = G.GroupId 
 where 1=2
```

If it runs successfully, uncomment the rest of the from clause line by line and run it each time.  If you don't get any errors, take away the count(*) from the select clause, and uncomment each field until you get an error.  Then you'll know what the problem is.

If it errors the first time, you probably have to qualify your tablenames with a database name, or whatever they call those in oracle.  I have had to do both of these types of things in my work.

```
from database.tablenam
```

and

```
 from "database"."tablename"
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do this question?

Comment: @Danis, I think you've problem with the table name GROUP, isn't it a reserved keyword?
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/ap_keywd.htm